# html dynamically filter a select options according to values in another select tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have two Select tags : the first one is dynamically populated with a php script (scans my non-empty folders) and give me the country codes as below:

```
         <select name="countries" id="countries"> 
         <option>fr</option>
         <option>gr</option>
         <option>it</option>
         <option>gr</option>
         <option>pl</option>
         <option>gb</option>
         <option>es</option>
         <option>pt</option>
                  ... 
         (dynamically populated from a php script)
    </select>
```

and the second SELECT is a full list  of countrie with their codes already populated:

```
    <select name="ctCodes" id="ctCodes">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="nl">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="bl">Belgium</option>
    <option value="rs">Russia</option>
                   ... 
      (full ready list with all countries and code as value)
    </select>
```

I don't want that my visitor choose from the first SELECT because it is just codes (fr, de, ..) but I want him to choose from a more comprehensive list with full name country (France, Germany..) where the options values will redirect him to the selected country : Ex he selects Germany, my function will take him : location.href = "xxx.php#" + element.value;) in this case 'de'.

How can I realize this: Create a Third SELECT tag which OPTIONS are added from the full dropdown list according to the first one ? ..is there a solution to just filter the fullname list in the 2nd SELECT tAG to keep only Options which are loaded in the first one ?  ...I know that's a nano second job for sql or ms-access !.. but is it possible to do it with html and javascript?
I am gratefull for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off generating this filtered select in php since you already have both country codes you need and full names. But since you just might not be able to change those here's javascript solution using jQuery:

```
var countryCodes = [],
    $filtered;

$('#countries option').each(function() {
    countryCodes.push($(this).text());
});

$filtered = $('#ctCodes').clone();
$filtered.attr('id', 'filtered');

$filtered.find('option').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (countryCodes.indexOf($this.val()) === -1) {
        $this.remove();
    }
});

$filtered.insertAfter('#ctCodes');
```

Comment: How can I use this code please ? ..in my html page ?

Comment: thank you so much for the answer I just tested it and works fine! but please just to finish this how can I get the option value from the new created Select tag : I mean (referring to your html code) When I select A or C from the created Select I need to get a or c .This value i must use it to redirect the visitor to the page ( location.href = "xxx.php#" + value;))

Comment: $filtered.on('change', function() {
  location.href = '#' + $(this).val();
 });

Comment: You saved me! Thank you so much ! I do appreciate Agedan.

Comment: Hi again, I really don't want to bother you but is there a way to do the same  routine in javascript (not Jquery) ?